# Exuberant Ctags 5.8 generating incomplete tags file for specific project

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

Using Arch Linux and I have Ctag 5.8 installed.

My **Go** project has this structure:

```
.
├── apply
│   └── apply.go
├── calculate
│   └── calculate.go
├── coupon.sqlite3
├── Godeps
│   ├── Godeps.json
│   └── Readme
├── main.go
├── Makefile
├── models
│   ├── cupom.go
│   ├── errorMessage.go
│   └── product.go
├── ping
│   └── ping.go
├── README.md
├── routes
│   └── routes.go
├── tags
├── tests
│   ├── apply_test.go
│   ├── calculate_test.go
│   ├── config.go
│   ├── coupon.sqlite3
│   └── fixtures
│       └── calculate.go
```

Running the command `ctags -R` or `ctags -R .` I have a `tags` file generated but with this content only.

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
```

Running the same command on other project generate the `tags` file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Exuberant Ctags installed, which does not support Go out of the box (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html).

There are a bunch of different alternative programs or ways to add it to your existing ctags:

- https://go-wise.blogspot.ca/2011/09/using-ctags-with-go.html
- https://github.com/eapache/starscope
- https://github.com/jstemmer/gotags
- http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html